# How do I find an object's specific content in a list?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of objects in a list that have a field called "number". Let the list be called "collected".

How would I find the object in the list that has "4" in its field?

I tried

```
class stats:
    def __init__(self, numba):
        self.Number = int(numba)

if (collected.Number == 4):
 #do stuff
```

However, I get an error that says
'list' object has no attribute 'number'  And even if this worked, how would I be able to see which index of the list has even found the "4"?

Comment: Because you called the field `Number`, not `number`.   Spelling matters.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to capitalize it here @TimRoberts

Comment: how do you define `stats`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands  Sorry, the class above was called `stats`

Comment: You need to create an instance of `stats` first. Like `x = stats(4)`. Then you can check if `x.Number == 4` since `x` is a `stats` object.

Comment: You said _Let the list be called "stats"_ but then  you said _the class above was called `stats`_. Which is it? A class is not a list.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have made adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
def findindex(lst,value):
    for i,n in enumerate(lst):
        if n.Number == value:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: What would n be in this case? Is it just a temporary object?

Comment: You can look up the `enumerate` function.  Each time through the loop, `i` will have the index of the item, and `n` will be the corresponding element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If `stats` is a list containing instances of `Data` then the `stats` list doesn't have a `Number` attribute, the elements do.

`stats[i].Number` would be legal, for any i in range(len(stats)).

Comment: How would I define that [i] in a conditional if I am trying to check if "4" is in the lists' object's attribute?